# What MSBUILD target determines user controls and adds them to the toolbox

Tags: .net, nant

Our setup
We currently use nANT to do our .net builds, so we directly call CSC.  We basicallyl override the Build target in the CSPROJ file.  We ocassionally will use MSBUILD to call targets like PrepareResources in our nAnt script for certain situations such as building WPF applicaitons where it needs additional files to compile.

In our main windows application, we have some user controls that are dropped into other forms, but when we go to view those forms in the visual studio designer, it comes up with a designer error.  We found that the reason for this error is that our user controls are not in the toolbox.    I ran a test from a basic applicatoin using standard visual studio winapp, created a user control, and built the application.  I noticed when i did this, it added the user control to the visual studio toolbox.  This process seems to take place somewhere within the msbuild BUILD target, which probably calls another target to do this.

FYI: We still use the "Play" button in visual studio to compile the csproj files.  The only difference is it calls a differnet "Build" target in the csproj file instead of our own.

I looked online and reviewed the list of msbuild targets and do not see anything that describes which target adds user controls to the toolbox.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE:
looks like calling MSBUILD for a csproj file on the command line doesn't add to the toolbox either.  It wont attempt to compile because of designer errors.   so now the question is, when you hit "play", besides msbuild build running, what other secret process is visual studio running to add to the toolbox?

Comment: Just a recommendation: its usually not a good idea to switch between msbuild and csc during your build, especially if your using VS. I'd be curious to see if this persists if you convert your script to use either operation 100%.